# Error when trying to parse trace using go tool trace

Tags: go, trace

I was following tutorial from [JustForFunc episode 22](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ySy3sR1LFCQ)

Added those two lines at the start of main() in main.go:

```
trace.Start(os.Stdout)
defer trace.Stop()
```

build the binary using `go build -o appName`

Timed it with `time ./appName > m.trace`

And finally tried to open trace with `go tool trace m.trace`
but got following error:

```
2017/11/10 19:15:38 Parsing trace...
failed to parse trace: unknown event type 50 at offset 0x16
```

Little more background on my code(golang 1.9, linux) : it is a server for GET requests built with gin-gonic. I added extra line of code `time.AfterFunc(20*time.Seconds, func(){closeServer()})` to close my server after 20 seconds so I could make few request to it and then stop server exiting program.

Comment: Probably something in you app is writing to stdout.

Comment: Your comment solved my issue. A fmt.Print... was writing to os.Stdout thus  had a mixed trace data with my other outputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem.
I followed this tutorial https://making.pusher.com/go-tool-trace/.
Added code to main :

```
f, err := os.Create("trace.out")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer f.Close()

err = trace.Start(f)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer trace.Stop()
// Your program here
```

And it seems to be working fine. I have no idea what could cause this problem :(

Comment: When trace.Start to os.Stdout can happen that  a fmt.Print.. or some other app's parts can start to write to os.Stdout too, thus  trace file become a mix of trace data with app's other outputs